# Different template for selected item in WPF combobox than items in composite collection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, compositecollection

I have a composite collection which consists of:

- combobox item with content 'Select a vendor'
- collection container with collection of Vendor objects, bound to a combobox `cmbVendor`

When a vendor is selected from the combobox, the `ToString()` method is called.
However, I want to display the value of the property `Name` of the selected Vendor object.
[image]
[image]

Setting the combobox property `DisplayMemberPath='Name'` works but then the 'Select a vendor' is not shown anymore on load, which is not desired.

Notes:

- sometimes a Vendor object is chosen from code-behind
- I can not override `ToString()` method of a Vendor object for other reasons

Any suggestions?

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:VendorConverter x:Key='VendorConverter' />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key='VendorsCollection'
                          Source='{Binding Vendors}'>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ComboBox Name='cmbVendor'
              SelectedItem='{Binding Vendor, Converter={StaticResource VendorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}'
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem='True'
              IsEditable='True'
              Width='{DynamicResource VendorCmbWidth}'>
      <!--Make sure "Select a vendor" is selected-->
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviour:SelectFirstItemBehavior />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType='{x:Type objects:Vendor}'>
          <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'>
            <TextBlock Text='{Binding Name}' />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType='{x:Type system:String}'>
          <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'>
            <TextBlock Text='{Binding }' />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.Resources>
      <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
          <ComboBoxItem Content='Select a vendor' />
          <CollectionContainer Collection='{Binding Source={StaticResource VendorsCollection}}' />
        </CompositeCollection>
      </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

    </ComboBox>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**VendorConverter**

```
internal class VendorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var vendor = value as Vendor;
            if (vendor != null)
            {
                return vendor;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var comboboxItem = value as ComboBoxItem;
            if (comboboxItem != null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var vendor = value as Vendor;
            if (vendor != null)
            {
                return vendor;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Behaviors**

```
internal class SelectFirstItemBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var combobox = sender as ComboBox;
            if (combobox != null && combobox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you set your default value as the object and make it the initial selected index?

Comment: @JoshAdams sometimes a Vendor object from the collection is chosen from code behind. So I can not set a default.

Comment: ahh @bertAR sorry my solution was not viable :(

Comment: override the ToString() to return this.Name? or did i not understand something? is your goal the same as in the images of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812405/wpf-combobox-loses-text-after-selection ?

Comment: @Milan Overriding the ToString() method is a possible solution. However, is this not possible in XAML only?

Comment: in xaml, you dont have access to the selected item data template of the combobox, so you cant do this only in xaml, but you can edit the template using some code-behind if you really have to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You should be able to combine `TextSearch.TextPath="Name"` for your normal items and `TextSearch.Text="Select a vendor"` directly assigned to your special item:

```
<ComboBox
    IsEditable="True"
    TextSearch.TextPath="Name">
...
```

and

```
<CompositeCollection>
    <ComboBoxItem Content='Select a vendor' TextSearch.Text="Select a vendor" />
    <CollectionContainer Collection='{Binding Source={StaticResource VendorsCollection}}' />
</CompositeCollection>
```

---

**Approach 2**

Just display a visual hint text when nothing is selected:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VendorsCollection}}"
    IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <VisualBrush x:Key="hintText" x:Shared="False"  AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Grid Background="White">
                            <TextBlock Margin="4 3" Text="Select a vendor"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource hintText}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource hintText}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

This way, you can keep your items collection clean of extra entries and use `TextSearch.TextPath` and similar properties for your actual items.

Comment: Try out `<ComboBoxItem Content='Dropdown content' TextSearch.Text="Textbox content" />` for a better understanding, which property is showing where ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first approach works! Unfortunately the alternative, 2nd approach did not work for me. The visual hint text is not shown.

Comment: @BertAR maybe your text is `null` instead of empty (would need a different trigger) or you have some initial selection... but as long as the first approach does the trick, this should be enough.

Comment: Indeed, my converter returns `null` for a `ComboBoxItem` (see question) i.e. for the case 'Select a vendor'. What modifications are needed for the trigger? It would be nice if I could use the 2nd approach as well.

Comment: @BertAR edited with two triggers to support null and empty texts (I'm not really sure if the `x:Shared="False"` is really needed, I just want to avoid possible problems)